# How to assign arrays to functions arguments?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am trying to assign values of my array to function's argument. I can't tell the length of the array but I want array value to be my functions argument. Ex:

```
$a= array {'1'=>'arg1', '2'=>'arg2', '3'=>'arg3'} ; //could have more than 3 values

function addArray('arg1','arg2','arg3'); //want to add values to argument.
```

Any thoughts? Thank a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call any function like that using [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array):

```
call_user_func_array('addArray', $a);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`func_get_args()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) to get all of the arguments inside of the function.

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
    if ($numargs >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "<br />\n";
    }
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
?>
```

Comment: ty, but minitech answer is more closer to what I need. +1 though.