# How to pass array of arguments to an method

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to pass array to a method and I want the method use array's values as arguments.

I posted a similar question on 
[How to assign arrays to functions arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576318/how-to-assign-arrays-to-functions-arguments)
thread but I am actually working on the class method here.

```
if (method_exists($testInstance, $method)){
  $a=array {'1'=>'aru1', '2'=>'arg2'}   //could have more than 2. it's dynamic
  call_user_func_array($testInstance->$method(), $a);  //this won't work.
}
```

Any thoughts? Thank a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to assign arrays to functions arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576318/how-to-assign-arrays-to-functions-arguments)

Comment: Mmmh... have you considered reading the documentation (second example)? http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php ... also it is helpful to follow further links, read about `callbable`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing an Array as Arguments, not an Array, in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744145/passing-an-array-as-arguments-not-an-array-in-php) -- second answer.

Comment: @FelixKling It seems only work in Static method. Am I wrong?

Comment: are you really assigning array using `{}`?

Comment: Works perfectly fine with normal methods. The example shows: `/* Call the $foo->bar() method with 2 arguments*/ $foo = new foo; call_user_func_array(array($foo, "bar"), array("three", "four"));`. Also this has been asked before and this is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/745112/218196. Why do you think the method must be static?

Comment: @NiftyDude no man, just typo.

Comment: @Jerry ok just making sure :)

Comment: @FelixKling Ty. totally my bad. Should have noticed that. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Felix suggested you need to pass a callable. For a class method that is an `array` with the object inatance (or class name if it is a static method) and the method name:

`call_user_func_array(array($obj,'myMethod'), $args)`